# javax look for property from the wrong ManagedBean

Tags: java, jsf

I can't understand why my app is taking a property not from the wright ManagedBean. I get the following error :

> Systeme.xhtml @37,116
>   target="#{sousSystemeView.idCurrentSousSysteme}": Property
>   [idCurrentSousSysteme] not found on type
>   [fr.tecup.htsm.ihm.EvenementRedouteView]
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: /utilisateur/Systeme.xhtml @37,116
>   target="#{sousSystemeView.idCurrentSousSysteme}": Property
>   [idCurrentSousSysteme] not found on type
>   [fr.tecup.htsm.ihm.EvenementRedouteView]

If someone has idea about the mistake it would be great!
Thank you all.

Here is my code :

**SousSystemeView**

```
@ManagedBean(name="sousSystemeView") @SessionScoped
public class SousSystemeView {

private final String link = "SousSysteme.jsf";
private SousSysteme currentSousSysteme = null;
private int idCurrentSousSysteme = -1;

public SousSysteme getCurrentSousSysteme() {
    return currentSousSysteme;
}

public void setCurrentSousSysteme(SousSysteme currentSousSysteme) {
    this.currentSousSysteme = currentSousSysteme;
}

public void loadSousSysteme(int idSousSysteme) {
    SousSysteme sousSysteme = SousSystemeDAO.loadSousSystemeById(idSousSysteme);
    setCurrentSousSysteme(sousSysteme);
}   

public void setIdCurrentSousSysteme (int idCurrentSousSysteme) {
    this.idCurrentSousSysteme = idCurrentSousSysteme;
}

public void loadSousSystemePage() {
    loadSousSysteme(idCurrentSousSysteme);

    ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    try {
        context.redirect(link);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
}
```

**EvenementRedouteView**

```
@ManagedBean(name="evenementRedouteView") @SessionScoped
public class EvenementRedouteView {

private final String link = "EvenementRedoute.jsf";
private EvenementRedoute currentEvenementRedoute = null;

public EvenementRedoute getCurrentEvenementRedoute() {
    return currentEvenementRedoute;
}

public void setCurrentEvenementRedoute(EvenementRedoute currentEvenementRedoute) {
    this.currentEvenementRedoute = currentEvenementRedoute;
}

public void loadEvenementRedoute(int idEvenementRedoute) {
    EvenementRedoute er = EvenementRedouteDAO.loadEvenementRedouteById(idEvenementRedoute);
    setCurrentEvenementRedoute(er);
}   

public void loadEvenementRedoutePage(int idEvenementRedoute) {
    loadEvenementRedoute(idEvenementRedoute);

    ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    try {
        context.redirect(link);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
}
```

**Systeme.xhtml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view>
 <f:loadBundle basename="systeme" var="systemeProps"></f:loadBundle>
 <h:head>
  <title>#{systemeProps.title}</title>
 </h:head>
 <h:body>
  <h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
  <h:outputStylesheet name="css/styleSysteme.css" />
  <header id="banniere">
   <h2>Hazards Tracking System Manager</h2>
  </header>
  <p:breadCrumb styleClass="path">
   <p:menuitem icon="fa fa-home" url="/utilisateur/index.jsf" />
  </p:breadCrumb>
  <div class="ui-g GridCSS">
   <div class="ui-g-1"></div>
   <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="ui-g-10 panelGridSysteme">
    <f:facet name="header">#{systemeView.currentSysteme.code}</f:facet>
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="panelGridSystemeInfos">
     <h:outputText value="#{systemeProps.name}" styleClass="panelGridSystemeInfosHeader" />
     <h:outputText value="#{systemeView.currentSysteme.nom}" />

     <h:outputText value="#{systemeProps.comment}" styleClass="panelGridSystemeInfosHeader" />
     <h:outputText value="#{systemeView.currentSysteme.commentaire}" />
    </p:panelGrid>
    <h:form>
     <p:dataGrid var="sousSysteme" value="#{systemeView.currentSysteme.sousSystemes}" columns="3" layout="grid" rows="12" paginator="false" styleClass="dataGridSousSystemes">
      <f:facet name="header">#{systemeProps.subSystems}</f:facet>
      <p:panel style="text-align:center">
       <p:panelGrid columns="1" columnClasses="label,value" layout="grid">
        <p:commandLink value="#{sousSysteme.code}" action="#{sousSystemeView.loadSousSystemePage}" ajax="false">
         <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{sousSystemeView.idCurrentSousSysteme}" value="#{sousSysteme.id}" />
        </p:commandLink>
        <h:outputText value="#{sousSysteme.nom}" />
       </p:panelGrid>
      </p:panel>
     </p:dataGrid>
    </h:form>
   </p:panelGrid>
  </div>
 </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out what's happening. I don't know why but the file EvenementRedouteView.class has not been rebuilt. I have created it with a cut and paste and the ManagedBean annotation name was thus "souSystemeView"...